# Scroll table wrapper div on mouse move over the table cells.(Chrome)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, google-chrome

I have table where dragging over cell will highlight the cell and it was working fine. In the recent version of Chrome on moving mouse over cell it is highlighting the cell, but the scrollbar is not moving down/up on mouse move.

code:

```
var SELECTION_START = 0;
var SELECTION_END = 1;

var selection = [getCellPos(), getCellPos()];

$tbl = $("#table-1");

function startSelection(event) {
    if (event.button === 2) { return false; }

    clearSelectionBorders();
    if (this !== $tbl.find('td.highlighted').last()[0]) {
        setSelection(this, SELECTION_START);
    }
    setSelection(this, SELECTION_END);

    $tbl.find("tr > *").mouseenter(moveSelection);
}

function stopSelection() {
    applySelectionHighlight();
    applySelectionBorders();

    $tbl.find("tr > *").off('mouseenter');
}

function moveSelection() {
    setSelection(this, SELECTION_END);
}

function setSelection(element, position) {
    element = $(element);
    var cellPos = getCellPos(element);
    selection[position] = cellPos;
    applySelectionHighlight();
}

function getCellPos(element) {
    element = $(element);
    if (element.length) return {
        col: element.index(),
        row: element.parent().parent().is($tbl.find('thead')) ? 0 : element.parent().index() + 1
    };
    return {
        row: -1,
        col: -1
    };
}

function getSelectionRect() {
    var rect = {
        x: 0,
        y: 0,
        width: 0,
        height: 0
    };
    rect.x = Math.min(selection[SELECTION_START].col, selection[SELECTION_END].col);
    rect.y = Math.min(selection[SELECTION_START].row, selection[SELECTION_END].row);
    rect.width = Math.max(selection[SELECTION_START].col, selection[SELECTION_END].col) + 1;
    rect.height = Math.max(selection[SELECTION_START].row, selection[SELECTION_END].row) + 1;

    if (rect.x === 0 && rect.width === 1) rect.width = $tbl.find('tr:first-child > *').length;
    if (rect.y === 0 && rect.height === 1) rect.height = $tbl.find('tr').length;

    return rect;
}

function applySelectionHighlight() {
    clearSelectionHighlight();

    var selectionRect = getSelectionRect();
    $tbl.find('thead tr > *').slice(selectionRect.x, selectionRect.width).addClass('highlighted');
    $tbl.find('tr').slice(selectionRect.y, selectionRect.height).each(function () {
        $(this).find('> th:first-child').addClass('highlighted');
        $(this).find('> *').slice(selectionRect.x, selectionRect.width).addClass('highlighted');
    });
}

function clearSelectionHighlight() {
    $tbl.find('tr > *').removeClass('highlighted');
}

function applySelectionBorders() {
    var allHighlighted = $tbl.find('.highlighted');
    allHighlighted.each(function (i, item) {
        var index = $(item).index();
        var b = $tbl.find("td.highlighted:last").addClass("autofill-cover");
        if (!$(item).prev().is('td.highlighted')) {
            $(item).addClass('left');
        }
        if (!$(item).next().is('td.highlighted')) {
            $(item).addClass('right');
        }
        if (!$(item).closest('tr').prev().find('td:nth-child(' + (index + 1) + ')').hasClass('highlighted')) {
            $(item).addClass('top');
        }
        if (!$(item).closest('tr').next().find('td:nth-child(' + (index + 1) + ')').hasClass('highlighted')) {
            $(item).addClass('bottom');
        }
    });
}

function clearSelectionBorders() {
    $tbl.find('td').removeClass('top bottom left right');
}

function clearAll() {
    selection = [getCellPos(), getCellPos()];
    clearSelectionHighlight()
    clearSelectionBorders();
}

$tbl.find("tr > *").mousedown(startSelection);
$(window).mouseup(stopSelection);

$(document).mousedown(function (event) {
    if ($(event.target).parents($tbl).length === 0) clearAll();
});
```

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ggbhat/8uL0jw3j/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behaviour isn't because of Javascript, it's because of the CSS you're using in your Fiddle:

```
table {
  user-select:none;
  -webkit-user-select:none;
}
```

The 'automatic' scrolling on dragging is fired because of the selection. This piece of CSS prohibits the selection of the table (and anything in it) and thus prevents the scrolling.

It would be better to still allow the user to select the table and its contents, and instead change the styling of selected elements like so:

```
::selection{
  background: transparent;
}
```

[::selection reference @ mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::selection)